# Why my app(struts+spring+jpa) works well on local machine, but GAE gave me '500 Server Error' when I request custom-i18n

Tags: google-app-engine, internationalization

============

```
When I try to test i18n, I found app works well in local machine, 
then when I deployed it to GAE, and I got '500 Server Error'.
```

**Here are the details:**

**I sent a request:**
    ENGLISH(http://pang-kimwah.appspot.com/local?lang=en_US&path=http://pang-kimwah.appspot.com/index.jsp)
    or
    中文(http://pang-kimwah.appspot.com/local?lang=zh_CN&path=http://pang-kimwah.appspot.com/index.jsp)

**I got this:**
    Error: Server Error
    The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
    Please try again in 30 seconds.

```
GAE Logs:
    Uncaught exception from servlet
    java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "user.language" "write")
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:375)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:565)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
        at java.util.Locale.setDefault(Locale.java:909)
        at java.util.Locale.setDefault(Locale.java:868)
        at com.jemhua.gae.web.action.Language.execute(Language.java:41)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:441)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:280)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:243)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.jemhua.utils.FixChineseEncoding.doFilter(FixChineseEncoding.java:29)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
        at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:188)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

**Finally:**
    Because struts2-tag <s:i18n> not supported/allowed by GAE, 
    so I new a tag <my:i18n> to instead of <s:i18n> via java.util.Locale.setDefault(language).
    **I thought(not sure) the key which cause of exception is: java.util.Locale.setDefault().**
    I don't know why app run well in local machine but GAE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Apparently, java.util.Locale.setDefault() is the cause of exception.
- So, I delete the statement: 'Locale.setDefault(new Locale(lang));' of
  action which java-file is associating i18n-request.
- Then i18n didn't work(always english), opened GAE Logs and I found
  the key of problem:

```
   Uncaught exception from servlet
    java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key welcome
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:395)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:392)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(ResourceBundle.java:355)
        at com.jemhua.gae.web.tags.I18N_Text.doStartTag(I18N_Text.java:73)
        at org.apache.jsp.i18n_jsp._jspx_meth_jemhua_005fi18n_005f0(i18n_jsp.java:137)
        ......
```

- Well, I rename all of the properties(e.g. shop_en_US.properties) file
  to be like this pattern shop_en.properties.
- Then, problem solved.